# Adding or duplicating directive dynamically does not get variable values from parent scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to figure out how I can dynamically duplicate my directive and at the same time maintain the variables from my parent scope.

here's a fiddle to make it clearer

http://jsfiddle.net/gdubdubs/FZ2hh/1/

```
m

yModule.directive('yodirective', function ($compile) {
        return {
            restrict:'E',
            scope:{},
            link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl){
                scope.options = scope.$parent.foobs;
                scope.selectedOption;
                scope.addNew = function(){
                    var d = $compile('<yodirective></yodirective>')(scope);
                   element.parent().append(d);
                };
            },
            template:'<div>' + 
                    '<select id="werp"' + 
                        'ng-model="selectedOption"' + 
                        'ng-options="opt as opt for opt in options"' + 
                        'ng-change="popDemBottles()" type="text">' +
                        '<option value="">select</option>' + 
                    '</select>' + 
                    '</div><div><a ng-click="addNew()" href="#">ADD</a></div>'
        };
    })
```

Basically when the new directive gets displayed it would not grab the values from my parent controller.

Thoughts on how I should I approach it? Also, should I have a controller property on the directive as well? I'm not really sure I need it and when to use it.

Thanks!

Comment: You should pass every parameter as Directive parameter.

Comment: what do you mean? on the compile?

Answer (score 0):

You can just access the parent scope directly. 
Just change this line

```
'ng-options="opt as opt for opt in options"' +
```

to

```
'ng-options="opt as opt for opt in foobs"' +
```

and get rid of the reference to the parent

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FZ2hh/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I just had to add the $parent when compiling

```
var d = $compile('<yodirective></yodirective>')(scope.$parent);
```